# How to move a document to a different id

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to move a document to a new `id` so that it becomes available at another `url` in the document API. There are two ways to do this:

1

- Delete the document at the old id
- Create the document with the new id

2

- Create the document with the new id
- Delete the document with the old id

Method 1 can result in the document not being returned in searches. Method 2 can result in the document being returned more than once in searches.

Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no way to make 'bulk' requests atomic in ElasticSearch. Have you considered having a searchable id field separate from _id? Then you can simply run an update on that document by updating the 'id' property.

There is one feature in ES that might be a solution, but I have not yet tried it yet. ES lets you map the _id field to a property field in the document. Doing so allows you to search on the property as if you are querying the id's directly. I do not know what will happen if you try to update the mapped field. You can find more info here:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-id-field.html

Comment: The problem with your suggestion is that you first need to do a query to find the actual `_id`. This `_id` is needed for an update. As far as I can tell now however this seems to be the best solution so far.

Comment: Using the `path` mapping to map the `_id` only affects the `POST`. When you update the field, the `_id` property stays the same (the initial extracted value).

Comment: bummer... in regards to your first comment though, I know this is a hacky solution, but why not mirror the _id, search_id model that you use in ES and apply it to your data store. For instance, if you are using oracle, when you create a document in ES, you insert the document id inside an oracle column. This requires more space, but you save yourself from an extra lookup.

Comment: depends on where you are getting your search_id. because you mentioned it is an ID, I had assumed this ID is fetched from a DB, so you can piggyback from the query that gets the searchID. This way you kill two birds with one stone. If this ID can be guessed by a human being without accessing a data source, then yes, it is another call to another system.

Answer (score 3):

When you create (index) or delete a document, this is only reflected in searches after the index has been refreshed. So in practice both your methods have the same result:
Until the index is refreshed

- the old document will be returned in searches but will not be available using the document API (GET /indexname/type/id)
- the new document will be available using the document API but not show up in searches.

As you do the index and delete operations in quick succession, perhaps even in a single bulk request, the ordering of the operations does not matter much. By default, the refresh interval is one second, so the discrepancy will remain for up to that time. You can force a refresh immediately by issuing a refresh command on the index:

```
curl -XPOST http://127.0.0.1:9200/testidx/_refresh
```

An illustration of the sequence of events is provided in the last section below.

A refresh can also be forced after a bulk request by adding the URL parameter `refresh=true`. So if you really need to change the ID of a document, I'd do it as follows:

1. Optionally disable automatic index refreshing
2. Issue a bulk request to

   1. CREATE new doc
   2. DELETE old doc
   3. REFRESH index
3. Re-enable automatic index refresh (if disabled in 1.)

Example:

To move document from ID 77 to ID 99:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/testidx/foo/_bulk?refresh=true --data-binary @bulk.json
```

Where the file `bulk.json` contains something like

```
{"index": {"_id": "123"}}
{ ... old document source ... }
{"delete": {"_id": "99"}}
```

However, do you really need to change the ID, or can you engineer around that requirement? Perhaps don't use the document API this way, but instead include e.g., a `"path"` field in every document and make a URL scheme based on that (based on the search API). Then you could move (change the URL path) a document by updating the document with a new `"path"` field.

### Search index refresh illustration

First add doc 77 and see it shows up in search:

```
+ curl -XPUT 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/testidx/foo/77' -d '{"boo": "baa"}'
{
  "_index" : "testidx",
  "_type" : "foo",
  "_id" : "77",
  "_version" : 1,
  "created" : true
}

+ curl -XPOST http://127.0.0.1:9200/testidx/_refresh
{"_shards":{"total":10,"successful":5,"failed":0}}

+ curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/testidx/foo/_search'
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "testidx",
      "_type" : "foo",
      "_id" : "77",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source":{"boo": "baa"}
    } ]
  }
}

+ curl -XPUT 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/testidx/_settings' -d '{"settings": { "index.refresh_interval": "-1"}}'
{
  "acknowledged" : true
}
```

Then add a new doc 99:

```
+ curl -XPUT 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/testidx/foo/99' -d '{"boo": "baa"}'
{
  "_index" : "testidx",
  "_type" : "foo",
  "_id" : "99",
  "_version" : 1,
  "created" : true
}
```

99 does not yet show up in search:

```
+ curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/testidx/foo/_search'
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "testidx",
      "_type" : "foo",
      "_id" : "77",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source":{"boo": "baa"}
    } ]
  }
}
```

... but is there in the document API:

```
+ curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/testidx/foo/99'
{
  "_index" : "testidx",
  "_type" : "foo",
  "_id" : "99",
  "_version" : 1,
  "found" : true,
  "_source":{"boo": "baa"}
}
```

After deleting 77, the search still shows 77 (but not 99):

```
+ curl -XDELETE 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/testidx/foo/77'
{
  "found" : true,
  "_index" : "testidx",
  "_type" : "foo",
  "_id" : "77",
  "_version" : 2
}

+ curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/testidx/foo/_search'
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "testidx",
      "_type" : "foo",
      "_id" : "77",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source":{"boo": "baa"}
    } ]
  }
```

But the document API no longer has 77:

```
+ curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/testidx/foo/77'
{
  "_index" : "testidx",
  "_type" : "foo",
  "_id" : "77",
  "found" : false
}
```

But after a refresh, the search results reflect the current contents:

```
+ curl -XPOST http://127.0.0.1:9200/testidx/_refresh
{"_shards":{"total":10,"successful":5,"failed":0}}

+ curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/testidx/foo/_search'
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "testidx",
      "_type" : "foo",
      "_id" : "99",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source":{"boo": "baa"}
    } ]
  }
}
```

Comment: This will give problems when updates will take place in more than one thread.

Comment: @EECOLOR Thanks for your input. Care to elaborate what will cause which kinds of problems?

Comment: Let's say that thread 1 removes the automatic refresh from the index to perform a delete/add pair. When the delete has been performed, thread 2 finishes with its delete/add pair and adds the automatic refresh to the index. The index then might be refreshed before the add of thread 1 is executed.

Answer (score 2):

A bit more involved, but if you are going to do this on a regular basis you could use index aliases. Basically you would change your application to use an index alias as a level of abstraction. You would then create a new index, load all of your existing documents and make the id changes you want to make. Finally you would change the index alias to point to the new index - this will happen atomically so that there is no downtime.

A similar process is described here (it's focused on changing mappings but document changes can be handled too):

http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/changing-mapping-with-zero-downtime/

Some more info on index aliases:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html

Comment: This might work, but in OP's case where he wants to re-id a single document, it may be highly inefficient and overkill to reindex every other document. Could be millions.